# Push to a child through tree structure with an array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tree, dynamic-arrays

I'm using [React Tree](https://github.com/react-component/tree) to build a tree structure for my app. I want to do a server request each time a node is expanded in order to load the children of said node. I'm using the `onExpand` property to get the *key* of the expanded node. This works great but the problem arises when the node is not on the first level of the tree.

When the node is not on the first level the `onExpand` property returns an array of *keys* that goes through each *key* that's been opened until the node is reached. My problem is that after I get from the children data (to be appended) from the server  I need to push it to the children of the expanded node and I need to traverse the tree data to do the push on the expanded node.

Example:

This is the data that builds the tree:

```
const data = [
        {
          key: 1,
          title: 'one',
          children: [
            {
              key: 2,
              title: 'two',
            },
            {
              key: 3,
              title: 'three',
              children: [
                {
                  key: 5,
                  title: 'five',
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              key: 4
              title: 'four',
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

If I expand the children with the *key* **5** then I get from `onExpand` an array with the keys **[1, 3, 5]**.

Then I get the children from **5** from my server and then I want to do something like:

```
data[1][3][5].children.push(/*datafromserver*/)
```

How can I do that?

This is dynamic so I'd need to somehow loop one level for each of the `onExpand`keys array.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, You have an array of some keys and a data of children and keys and you want to find the correct child.
You can do this with a recursion.
for example:

```js
function findItem(children, keys){
 if (keys.length === 0) {
  return;
  }

 var key = keys[0];
  
 var child = (children || []).filter(function(child){
  return child.key === key
 })[0];

 if (child) {
  if (keys.length === 1) {
   return child;
    } else {
   return findItem(child.children, keys.slice(1));
    }
  }
}

var data = [
        {
          key: 1,
          title: 'one',
          children: [
            {
              key: 2,
              title: 'two',
            },
            {
              key: 3,
              title: 'three',
              children: [
                {
                  key: 5,
                  title: 'five',
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              key: 4,
              title: 'four'
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
      
var itemFound = findItem(data, [1,3,5]);
console.log(itemFound.key);
//add some data to is children - itemFound.children.push(someData);
```